# Which of "\langle" and "\left<" should I use in dirac braket and expectation value?

Tags: formatting, brackets

`\langle` is smaller and `\left<` is bigger. But which one should I use in dirac braket and expectation value? Is there a standard practice?

Comment: @Mico they are the same in normal. But different in size when a fraction or something big in size like parenthesis is used inside the bracket. Consider ` \left<\frac{1}{2}\right| = \langle\frac{1}{2}\|`

Comment: @Mico Yes, thats right.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Take a look on the `braket` package which is designed for usage of `<` and `>` in `bra-ket` notation of Hilbert space states.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}

\usepackage{braket}

\begin{document}
$\ket{n}$% Harmonic oscillator state

$\bra{n}$

$\braket{n|a^{\dagger}a|n}$% Number operator

$\braket{\Phi|\dfrac{\partial^2}{\partial t^2}|\Phi}$

$\Braket{\Phi|\dfrac{\partial^2}{\partial t^2}|\Phi}$

\end{document}
```

[image]

As can be seen from the example the second usage of `\braket` command is undesireful in the output, due to the fraction. Use `\Braket` rather then.

There are also `\Bra` and `\Ket` commands.

Another possibility is to use the `physics` package -- this can't be mixed with `braket` however since the macro names clash.

```
\documentclass{article}


\usepackage{physics}

\begin{document}

$\expval{A}$

$\bra{\phi}\ket{\Psi}$

\end{document}
```

Comment: however, does `\bra` `\ket` use `\langle` or `\left<`?